# Spark: how to get the number of written rows?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm wondering if there is a way to know the number of lines written by a Spark save operation. I know that it's enough to do a count on the RDD before writing it, but I'd like to know if there is a way to have the same info without doing it.

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: Its may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413423/count-number-of-rows-in-an-rdd

Comment: @amit_kumar I don't think it's a duplicate, I think he wants to count it and save it without having to pass over the data twice.

Comment: This is a question about RDDs, but if you're using DataFrames on Spark 3.3+ check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77996296/877069) (Python) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77996592/877069) (Scala).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you really want you can add custom listener and extract number of written rows from `outputMetrics`. Very simple example can look like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}

var recordsWrittenCount = 0L

sc.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() { 
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
    synchronized {
      recordsWrittenCount += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten 
    }
  }
})

sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 2).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/foobar")
recordsWrittenCount
// Long = 10
```

but this part of the API is intended for internal usage.

Comment: thank you, but using Spark 1.5.2 it doesn't work. Instead you have to do: `recordsWrittenCount += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.get.recordsWritten`

Comment: Like mentioned it is an internal API so there is no guarantee it will be stable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use atomic recordsWrittenCount instead of synch block?

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing when writing records using:
`spark.write.avro(...)`

Comment: for me recordsWritten is always 0 in structuredstreaming

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer more closely matches the OPs specific needs (as made explicit in various comments), nevertheless this answer will suit the majority.

The most efficient approach is to use an Accumulator: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators

```scala
val accum = sc.accumulator(0L)

data.map { x =>
  accum += 1
  x
}
.saveAsTextFile(path)

val count = accum.value
```

You can then wrap this in a useful pimp:

```scala
implicit class PimpedStringRDD(rdd: RDD[String]) {
  def saveAsTextFileAndCount(p: String): Long = {
    val accum = rdd.sparkContext.accumulator(0L)

    rdd.map { x =>
      accum += 1
      x
    }
    .saveAsTextFile(p)

    accum.value
  }
}
```

So you can do

```scala
val count = data.saveAsTextFileAndCount(path)
```

Comment: I know this kind of approach, but I'd like to avoid it for 2 main reasons: using it in a transformation means that the result cannot be trusted in case of some failures; there is anyway a (little) overhead. I was just wondering if there is a counter accessible someway, like there is in mapreduce, since in the web UI the number of rows written is shown...

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer... even though I keep on wondering how they can show this info on the web UI if there is no internal counter...

Comment: @mark91 Ah, well, you could clone the UI code and dig through it I guess. Having read the documentation, the code I've given is fine.  (Spark says it protects against restarted tasks). It seems what you want to protect against is when an RDD is transformed multiple times, but the code I've given the rdd isn't accessible outside the Pimps scope. It will only accumulates before writing, and only accumulate once.

Comment: count = rdd.count(); rdd.saveAsTextFile(p); Is this anyway better?

Comment: @amit_kumar If RDD is not cached this should be more efficient than separate count because data will be materialized only once.

Comment: As far as I understand modifying accumulator in transformation action (i.e. map in your case) might result in invalid value.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at

```
taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables
```

You will see that it is bundled with following `AccumulableInfo` in `ListBuffer` in a sequential order.

```
AccumulableInfo(1,Some(internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime),Some(33),Some(33),true,true,None), 
AccumulableInfo(2,Some(internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime),Some(32067956),Some(32067956),true,true,None), AccumulableInfo(3,Some(internal.metrics.executorRunTime),Some(325),Some(325),true,true,None), 
AccumulableInfo(4,Some(internal.metrics.executorCpuTime),Some(320581946),Some(320581946),true,true,None), 
AccumulableInfo(5,Some(internal.metrics.resultSize),Some(1459),Some(1459),true,true,None), 
AccumulableInfo(7,Some(internal.metrics.resultSerializationTime),Some(1),Some(1),true,true,None), 
AccumulableInfo(0,Some(number of output rows),Some(3),Some(3),true,true,Some(sql)
```

You can clearly see that number of output rows are on the 7th position of the listBuffer, so the correct way to get the rows being written count is

```
taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables(6).value.get
```

We can get the rows written by following way ( I just modified @zero323's answer)

```
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}

var recordsWrittenCount = 0L

sc.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() { 
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
    synchronized {
      recordsWrittenCount += taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables(6).value.get.asInstanceOf[Long] 
    }
  }
})

sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 2).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/foobar")
recordsWrittenCount
```

Comment: It is not that simple unfortunately. 
I had several tasks  ie: stage1"s task outputted 100 rows , stage2's task(which writes into the DB) outputted 30rows.  So just adding them up naively would result 130 rows instead of 30.