# Spark lazy asynchronous count in scala

Tags: scala, asynchronous, apache-spark, count

I am currently building a Spark application and I'd like to log some stats from my intermediary RDDs. All I need is the size of the RDDs at different steps of the transformations.

The transformations are linear, therefore I don't need to cache anything, except to call `.count()` (which doesn't need to be accurate nor synchronous).

I could use `countAsync` to become asynchronous:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(path)
val (values, malformedRows) = parse(rawData)
values.countAsync.onComplete(size => logger.info(s"${malformedRows.count} malformed rows while parsing ${path} (${size} successfully parsed)"))
val result = values
    .map(operator)
    .filter(predicate)
result.countAsync.onComplete(size => logger.info(s"${size} final rows"))
result.saveAsTextFile(output)
```

However, my understanding is that the `countAsync` will trigger a new action (as `count` does). And since my RDDs will eventually be computed (by the last `saveAsTextFile` action), I'm wondering if it is possible to capitalize on the last action in order to log the stats without creating new actions.

Is there any way to have an approximate asynchronous count without triggering a new action? In other word to have a lazy `count()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: how to get the number of written rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37496650/1560062)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking for a way to count temporary RDDs as well, not only the one that is written into a file.
But it seems that using an accumulator may solve this problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Before using accumulators be sure to understand their behavior in transformations. You'll find some basic info in the docs.

Comment: I will. My issue with accumulators is that if I want to count in a submethod that does one filter, I need to put my log statement after writing the file. Thus I have code split into the local method that counts and the end of my job that logs
I could probably design something that will be kind of generic, but it seems more complex than it should.