# How to get the number of records written (using DataFrameWriter's save operation)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to get the number of records written when using spark to save records?  While I know it isn't in the spec currently, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
val count = df.write.csv(path)
```

Alternatively, being able to do an inline count (preferably without just using a standard accumulator) of the results of a step would be (almost) as effective.  i.e.:

```
dataset.countTo(count_var).filter({function}).countTo(filtered_count_var).collect()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [`SparkListener`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) that can intercept `onTaskEnd` or `onStageCompleted` events that you could use to access task metrics.

Task metrics give you the accumulators Spark uses to display metrics in SQL tab (in Details for Query).

[image: web UI / Details for Query]

For example, the following query:

```
spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  csv("../datasets/people.csv").
  limit(10).
  write.
  csv("people")
```

gives exactly 10 output rows so Spark knows it (and you could too).

[image]

---

You could also explore Spark SQL's [QueryExecutionListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.util.QueryExecutionListener):

> The interface of query execution listener that can be used to analyze execution metrics.

You can register a `QueryExecutionListener` using [`ExecutionListenerManager`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager) that's available as `spark.listenerManager`.

```
scala> :type spark.listenerManager
org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager

scala> spark.listenerManager.
clear   clone   register   unregister
```

I think it's closer to the "bare metal", but haven't used that before.

---

[@D3V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340767/d3v) (in the comments section) mentioned accessing the `numOutputRows` SQL metrics using `QueryExecution` of a structured query. Something worth considering.

```
scala> :type q
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> :type q.queryExecution.executedPlan.metrics
Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric]

q.queryExecution.executedPlan.metrics("numOutputRows").value
```

Comment: Have you tested `SparkListener` with SQL? I've done some crude testing before, and it didn't capture  SQL write metrics. `ExecutionListenerManager` is the way to go, and has nice example in the tests.

Comment: No, I have not used either interface with SQL. Something I only know in theory...still.

Comment: If you're using SparkListenerTaskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten, keep in mind there was a [bug there solved only in Spark 2.3.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22605)

Comment: Doesnt work. q.queryExecution.executedPlan.metrics is totally empty

Comment: @beatrice I remember you have to execute the query first to access the metrics. They're accumulators so they filled in after tasks (of the `q` query) are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DataFrames on Spark 3.3+, then the modern way to do this is with an [Observation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Observation.html).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, max}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Observation

val data = spark.range(1000)
val observation = Observation("write-metrics")

data
.observe(
    observation,
    count("*").alias("count"),
    max("id").alias("max_id"),
)
.write.parquet("output")

// Must call this after an action on `data` populates the observation.
observation.get
```

You can compute multiple metrics at once as part of an observation. In this example, we're counting the number of rows written as well as tracking the maximum value for `id`.

Here's what the observation results look like:

```scala
scala> observation.get
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] =
        Map(count -> 1000, max_id -> 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) to count the rows as they are written out:

```scala
val count = df.sparkSession.sparkContext.longAccumulator("row count")
val counted = df.map(row => { count.add(1); row })(df.encoder)
counted.write.parquet("my file")
count.value
```

Since it has to decode/encode each row for us, I'm not sure this is faster than just checking the output:

```scala
df.sparkSession.read.parquet("my file").count
```

Parquet stores the row counts as metadata, so it might be fast enough to check.