# pyspark: count number of rows written

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, monitoring, metrics

When I do

```
df: DataFrame = ...
df.write.parquet('some://location/')
```

Can I track and report (for monitoring) the number of rows that was just written to `some://location`?

```
df.write.parquet('some://location/')
# I imagine something like:
spark_session.someWeirdApi().mostRecentOperation().number_of_rows_written
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37496650/877069 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43934168/877069

Answer (score 4):

After doing some digging I found a way to do it:

- You can register a QueryExecutionListener (beware, this is annotated `@DeveloperApi` in the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/util/QueryExecutionListener.scala#L50)) via [py4j's callbacks](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#implementing-java-interfaces-from-python-callback)
- but you need to start the callback server and stop the gateway manually at the end of the run of your application.

This is inspired by a [post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Counting-the-number-of-rows-after-writing-to-a-dataframe-to/td-p/203256) in the cloudera community, I had to port it to a more recent spark version (this uses spark 3.0.1, the answer suggested over there uses the deprecated `SQLContext`) and pyspark (using a py4j callback).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame


class Listener:
    def onSuccess(self, funcName, qe, durationNs):
        print("success", funcName, durationNs, qe.executedPlan().metrics())
        print("rows", qe.executedPlan().metrics().get("numOutputRows").value())
        print("files", qe.executedPlan().metrics().get("numFiles").value())
        print("bytes", qe.executedPlan().metrics().get("numOutputBytes").value())

    def onFailure(self, funcName, qe, exception):
        print("failure", funcName, exception, qe.executedPlan().metrics())

    class Java:
        implements = ["org.apache.spark.sql.util.QueryExecutionListener"]


def run():
    spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 3), columns=["foo", "bar", "qux"]))

    gateway = spark.sparkContext._gateway
    gateway.start_callback_server()

    listener = Listener()
    spark._jsparkSession.listenerManager().register(listener)

    df.write.parquet("/tmp/file.parquet", mode='overwrite')

    spark._jsparkSession.listenerManager().unregister(listener)

    spark.stop()
    spark.sparkContext.stop()
    gateway.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: I have wrapped this solution in a nice API in a python package: https://github.com/scravy/pysparkextra#sparkmetrics

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DataFrames on Spark 3.3+, then the modern way to do this is with [DataFrame.observe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.observe.html).

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, max
from pyspark.sql import Observation

data = spark.range(1000)
observation = Observation("write-metrics")
(
    data
    .observe(
        observation,
        count("*").alias("count"),
        max("id").alias("max_id"),
    )
    .write.parquet("output")
)

# Must call this after an action on `data` populates the observation.
observation.get
```

You can compute multiple metrics at once as part of an observation. In this example, we're counting the number of rows written as well as tracking the maximum value for `id`.

Here's what the observation results look like:

```py
>>> observation.get
{'count': 1000, 'max_id': 999}
```