# How to find number of records in rdd without using count?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*],"name")
val data = sc.textFile(filepath)
println(data.count)
```

If my data is more than one gb and I am using some more functions and there also I am again count the subset of this same data using "rdd.count" .I think its become slow.So is there any solution to find the number of records rather than count and should be faster than rdd.count

Comment: this is in Java, but the answer still applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413423/count-number-of-rows-in-an-rdd

Comment: but this is not faster than rdd.count

Comment: read the answer:  _"There is no faster way."_

Comment: Ok thanks Petronella